# Could anyone explain this unexpected point output to me?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int i = 2;
int j = 8;
int *p = &i;
int *q = &j;
```

So at this point it is obvious that p is pointing to 2 and q is pointing to 8.

```
(*p) = (*q);
```

Now pointer p points to q which in turn points to j. j = 8 so p should point to the value 8. The last part is:

```
i++;
printf("%d %d\n", *p, *q);
```

The output of this is 9 8. However, I do not understand this because p is pointing to q so shouldn't pointer p be unaffected by this change as it is pointing to 8? Why does 8 get incremented by 1? p was originally pointing to i, but it changed pointers to q so I do not understand this result.

Edit: Thanks to all of you. All of your explanations make perfect sense to me.

Comment: (*p) = (*q); is just assigning j to i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you want to make pointer `p` point to `q`, you need to do this:

```
p = q;
```

or

```
p = &j;
```

This line:

```
(*p) = (*q);
```

Is the same as:

```
i = j;
```

So, when you make:

```
i++;
```

Which is the same as:

```
(*p)++;
```

Which will lead to your output:

```
8 9
```

Because `p` still points to `i` (`p = &i`) and (`q = &j`) and `i = 9` and `j = 8`

Answer (score 1):

> `(*p) = (*q);`
>
> Now pointer p points to q which in turn points to j.

No.  You have not changed the value of `p`; you've changed the value of what `p` *points to*.  You've assigned the value 8 (the result of the expression `*q`) to the variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(*p) = (*q);
```

assings what `q` points to to what `p` points to, which in this case is equivalent to:

```
i = j;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = q
```

assigns pointer `q` to pointer `p`. Your

```
(*p) = (*q)
```

takes out a value that `q` points to, and stores it into location pointed at by `p` - they both now point at an `8`, but a *different* 8. Then you increment one of them; the other is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the way the indirection operator `*` works.

Here is what's going on: the pointer-to-value mapping starts off like this:

```
p -----> i (which is equal to 2)
q -----> j (which is equal to 8)
```

The indirection operator `*` works in a way that when you do this `(*p) = (*q)`, you say that the item pointed to by `p` must be assigned the value pointed to by `q`. Considering the configuration of the pointers above, the result would be exactly the same as if you did `i = j`.

Now the situation changes to the following:

```
p -----> i (which is now equal to 8)
q -----> j (which is still equal to 8)
```

Finally, you perform `i++`, resulting in the following:

```
p -----> i (which is now equal to 9)
q -----> j (which is still equal to 8)
```

That's why 8 and 9 get printed.

Answer (score 0):

No, p is not pointing to q.

(*p) refers to the "content of p", so the following:

```
(*p) = (*q)
```

will copy the content of q to the content of p, but p and q will remain unchanged; p and q will still point at two different locations of memory.